# Vuejs: How to trigger render function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I currently have a component with a render function, to which I send data using a slot.

In short my component looks as follows:

```
export default {

    render(createElement){
        return createElement(
            'div', {
                'class' : 'className'
            },
            this.$slots.default
        )
    }

}
```

There is a bit more inside the render function that creates multiple elements and puts the slot content in each of the element (which is the reason I'm using a render function), but that's not relevant for this example.

I have another component which has this template:

```
<Component1>
    <div>foo</div>
</Component1>
```

(component 1 being the component with the render function).

This all works nicely, but the problem is that when the word 'foo' changes, the component doesn't get updated. I can send a prop to the component to check wether the content gets changed (by putting a watcher on the prop), but how can I force the component to run the render function again?

Thanks!

Comment: As a side-note, from your description it sounds like you might be misusing the render function, read [this docs page](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Constraints).

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, reproduction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . Even a jsfiddle will work.

Comment: How do you change the word foo? Is it changed outside of VueJs? Do you make a direct access with JS to it?

Comment: Here you can find a basic [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/L1e1us4f/). But it's with-out the problem where a re-render is necessary. Maybe you could add that and share the updated fiddle.